# Install a MSI based on whether a windows service is disabled or not

Tags: wix, windows-installer, exe

I have a Bundle setup such that it installs a combination about 4 msis, like, MSI_1 -> MSI_2 -> MSI_3 -> MSI_4.

I want the MSI_4 to be installed only if a particular windows service is NOT disabled, i.e. Don't install if the windows service (say ABC) is disabled. I can probably use a CustomAction and run the command

```
"Get-WMIObject win32_service -filter "name='ABC'" -computer "." | select -expand state"
```

to check for the state. But how do I use that(can I use that?) to determine whether to execute the installer or not. Mind you, all the 4 MSIs have their own project and they are combined under the umbrella of one VS solution. I don't have to go the CustomAction route, so if you have anything else in mind I am open to try that as well.

Thanks for your time and help in advance. Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Can you give a reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will answer my own question here, since I found the solution. What I didn't know was the services listing was also available in the registry setting and one can use Util:RegistrySearch element in the wxs where we are doing the Chain element. One can modify the state of the service from Running to Disabled to observe the change in the value and can set the InstallCondition accordingly.

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="System\CurrentControlSet\Services\ABC"
                     Win64="yes"
                     Value="Start"
                     Variable="State" />
```

And the Chain element will be like:

```
<MsiPackage Id="package"
              Cache="no" Vital="yes"
              DisplayInternalUI="no"
              ForcePerMachine="yes"
              SourceFile="package.msi"
              InstallCondition="(State = <condition>)" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: An alternative is in your BootstrapperApplication's "OnPlanPackageBegin" when passed the package Id that represents your fourth msi, programatically determine the state of the service then your bootstrapper application can override the requested state to Present or Absent.